# Dual-boot WIndows 10 (GPT) and Ubuntu 18.04 (DOS): Is that a problem?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, gpt, ms-dos, grub4dos

I have a SSD with Windows 10 and a disklabel type gpt and a HDD with Ubuntu 18 and a disklabel type DOS. I have read that having 2 disks with 2 different OS, and one disk is formatted to gpt and the other to dos can cause problems. I have a Acer Aspire machine, so I only have UEFI settings (there is no option to select legacy boot manager). The output of the command `sudo fdisk -l|grep -A4 /dev/sd` is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
--
/dev/sda1  *         2048    976895    974848   476M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda2          978942  13883391  12904450   6,2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3        13883392 599820287 585936896 279,4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       599820288 976771071 376950784 179,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5          978944  13883391  12904448   6,2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/sdb: 119,2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
--
/dev/sdb1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3     239616 247971839 247732224 118,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  247971840 250068991   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/loop8: 163,7 MiB, 171618304 bytes, 335192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
```

Should I be worried about it? Everything seems to be working just fine. I can boot in Windows and Ubuntu normally. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It can work, its just that gpt is the newer better partitioning. You just about cannot convert Windows from MBR to gpt, but can convert Ubuntu, if you want. And at minimum would have to reinstall grub.Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html
You are only able to dual boot from UEFI, not from grub. But if willing to live with that you can. Windows requires gpt, and really Ubuntu should also, but does not.

Comment: Am I only able tu boot from UEFI? Because when I turn on my computer, a grub screen appears from which I can choose Ubuntu or Windows... @oldfred

Comment: It works because both installs are UEFI. And Ubuntu does let you install in UEFI mode to 35 year old MBR partitioned drive.